# .htaccess issues with Wordpress in root directory and separate installation in subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a working installation of Wordpress in top-level directory.  I'm trying to place a separate Wordpress installation - a kind of "development environment" with its own code files and database, in a subdirectory.

At the moment, all URL's in the subdirectory have a 404 page not found error.

.htaccess for subdirectory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /v3
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess for main directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^laddercapital\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.laddercapital.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?v3/
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Ideas?

Comment: Was having a very similar problem myself here: http://serverfault.com/questions/336511/installing-wordpress-in-sub-directory-with-htaccess-in-root-directory
Would be great to see an answer here...

Comment: OMG, this question was 9 months ago, I thought it was just now.....shooooot.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `RewriteBase` in the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory. E.g.

```
RewriteBase /v3/wordpress
```

Comment: My bad - I mislabeled the main directory v subdirectory .htaccess files.  As you can now see, the subdirectory already has the RewriteBase...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for the .htaccess in the subdirectory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /v3/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /v3/index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Source: [WP 404 not found subdirectory](http://maurisource.com/en/2-htaccess-bypass-wp-404-not-found-install-error-subfolder/)